# Spark and continuous processing of data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am new to Spark but I am reading up as much as I can. I have a small project where multiple data files (in gzip) are going to continuously land in an S3 bucket every hour. I need to be able to open/read these gzip files and consolidate/aggregate data across them. So, I need to look at them in a holistic fashion. How, what techniques and tools from Amazon AWS can be used? Do I create interim files in a S3 folder or hold Dataframes in memory or use some database and blow away the data after each hour? So, I am looking for ideas more than a piece of code.

So far, in AWS, I have written a pyspark script that reads 1 file at a time and create an output file back in output S3 folder. But that leaves me with multiple output files for each hour. Would be nice if there was 1 file for a given hour.

From technology perspective, I am using an EMR cluster with just 1 master and 1 core node, Pyspark and S3. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use an AWS Glue ETL job written in PySpark. Glue jobs can be scheduled to run every hour.
I suggest reading the entire dataset, performing your operations, and then moving the data to another long-term storage location.

If you are working on a few GB of data, a PySpark job should complete within minutes. There's no need to keep an EMR cluster running for an hour if you'll only need it for 10 minutes. Consider using short-lived EMR clusters or a Glue ETL job.

Athena supports querying GZipped data. If you're performing some sort of analysis, maybe executing an Athena query with a time range will work?

You could also use a CTAS (Create Table As Select) statement in Athena to copy data to a new location, and performing basic ETL on it at the same time.

What exactly does your PySpark code do?

Comment: The pyspark code read S3 file into a RDD, calculates datetime based on epoch seconds for certain records, sums data based on criteria, creates final single RDD and saves to output S3 bucket for now. But this will be 128 times in 1 hour. Since data is dispersed in 128 input files, I need a better way to look at it holistically. The data for 1 hour (128 files) is 1 GB zipped collectively. Also, I tried to create EMR using lambda but couldn't bootstrap xmltodict and boto3 libraries. I even put a question on stackoverflow but didn't find soln.